# Unable to create multiple Controls on Button Click Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, controls

I'm trying to create a `asp:UploadFile` control dynamically on button click event. After creating the first control it won't create a second or third one. Below is my code.

```
protected void AddFileInputControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileUpload image = new FileUpload();
    image.ID = "image";
    fileinputs_div.Controls.Add(image);
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give unique ID for each `image`, for example using global counter :

```
private int counter;
protected void AddFileInputControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileUpload image = new FileUpload();
    image.ID = "image" + counter++;
    fileinputs_div.Controls.Add(image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net doesn't save the dynamically created control for the next calls. That means you would need to create them every PostBack. Something like this:

```
private int _counter = 0

protected void AddFileInputControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _counter; i++)
    {
        fileinputs_div.Controls.Add(new FileUpload()
        {
            ID = string.Format("image #{0}", i);
        });    
    }

    _counter++;
}
```